# mod_dav_svn linked to the SVN binaries?

Tags: svn, mod-dav-svn

Apologies in advance for the possibily-incorrect terminology and probably-naïve question!

Is the Apache module mod_dav_svn linked to the SVN binaries in one way or another?

I am doing the initial research for an upgrade to our current 1.4.x SVN installation, and I am wondering whether compiling the latest 1.6.x version means we also need to compile a new version of mod_dav_svn, or does the mod_dav_svn just act as a proxy and invoke the svn binaries itself, meaning that we could swap in the new version without needing to do anything to the Apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

What operating system?  Looks like mod_dav_svn depends on subversion so I think you would have to recompile all the packages:

```
vince@f12 ~ > yum deplist mod_dav_svn
Loaded plugins: presto, refresh-packagekit
Dropbox                                                                                          |  951 B     00:00
google-chrome                                                                                    |  951 B     00:00
google-chrome/primary                                                                            | 1.4 kB     00:00
google-chrome                                                                                                       3/3
updates/metalink                                                                                 | 2.8 kB     00:00
Finding dependencies:
package: mod_dav_svn.x86_64 1.6.13-1.fc12.1
  dependency: libsvn_repos-1.so.0()(64bit)
   provider: subversion.x86_64 1.6.5-2.fc12
   provider: subversion-libs.x86_64 1.6.13-1.fc12.1
  dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit)
   provider: glibc.x86_64 2.11-2
   provider: glibc.x86_64 2.11.2-3
  dependency: libc.so.6()(64bit)
   provider: glibc.x86_64 2.11-2
   provider: glibc.x86_64 2.11.2-3
  dependency: subversion = 1.6.13-1.fc12.1
   provider: subversion.x86_64 1.6.13-1.fc12.1
  dependency: libz.so.1()(64bit)
   provider: zlib.x86_64 1.2.3-23.fc12
   ...
```

You could also [download subversion](http://www.wandisco.com/download/subversion) from a company that already has it compiled.